# Caffe fine-tuning vs. starting from scratch

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, caffe

**Context**: let's say I have trained a CNN on `datasetA` and I've obtained `caffeModelA`.

**Current situation**: new pictures arrive so I can build a new dataset, `datasetB`

**Question**: would these two situations lead to same caffemodel?

1. merge `datasetA` and `datasetB` and train the net from scratch.
2. perform some *fine-tuning* on existing `caffeModelA` by training it only on `datasetB` (as explained here: http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/finetune_flickr_style.html)

It might seem a dumb question, but I'm not really sure about its answer. And it's really important because if the two approximations lead to same result I can save time by performing number 2.

*Note: bear in mind that it's the same problem, so no need to change architecture here, I just plan to add new images to the training.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Flicker-style example the situation is a bit more generic. They use the weights of first layers from a model trained for a different classification task and employ it for a new task, training only a new last layer and fine-tuning the first layers a bit (by setting a low learning rate for those pretrained layers). Your case is similar but more specific, you want to use the pretrained model to train the exact architecture for the exact same task but with an extension of your data.

If your question if whether Option 1. will produce **exactly** the same model (all resulting weights are equal) as Option 2. Then no, most probably not.

In Option 2. the network is trained for iterations of `dataset A` then for `dataset B` then `dataset A` again..and so on (assuming both were just concatenated together).
While in Option 1. will have the network trained for some iterations/epochs on `dataset A`, then later continue learning for iterations/epochs on only `dataset B` and that's it. So the solver will see a different sequence of gradients in both options resulting in two different models. That's from a strict theoretical perspective.

If you ask from a practical perspective, the two options will probably end up with very similar models. How many **epochs** (not iterations) did you train on `dataset A` ? say N **epochs**, then you can safely go with Option 2. and train your existing model further on `dataset B` for the same number of **epochs** and same learning rate and batch size.

Comment: Perfect answer sir! My intuition was that the sequence of gradients would be different, but I needed confirmation and you convinced me :) Actually this is how I do it right now: starting from scratch - even though results could be very similar - but maybe it's worth it to give it a practical try and compare. Thanks a lot for your answer! (by the way, I'm training on quite a big number of epochs, 50000)

Comment: @GuiemBosch careful...caffe goes by iterations, not epochs.  number of epoch = (batch size * num-iterations)/#training-samples.